# Checking Radio Button Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing a sample project named: **Tennis Club Management** using javascript,HTML,CSS,Bootstrap. In this project, I have a **managePlayers.html** page in which there are two buttons **Add Players** & **Show Players**. On clicking **Add Players** button, a table with input fields appears below, which contains **ID,DOB,Name,Gender,Contact, 2 radio buttons for gender a SAVE button.**.

**Note :** What i need to do is that when i click the **save** button , it should check whether either of the radio is selected or not (Gender : male/female ..in this case). I couldn't figured it out yet.Below are the code files and screenshots

**Jsfiddle link :** https://jsfiddle.net/mohitsharma1991/40yz7tv6/1/

**index.js**

```
//---------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING TABLE FOR ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION--------------- 


function addplayers() {

    // playerIDvalue += 1;
    document.querySelector("#customerregistration").style.display = "block";
    if (istableCreated) {
        document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "none";
    }
    // document.querySelector(".playerID").value = playerIDvalue;
}



//--------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SAVING CUSTOMER INFORMATION OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE-----------------------------



function savePlayer() {
    console.log("data saved successfully...");
    var playerBirthday = document.querySelector(".playerbirthday").value;
    var playerName = document.querySelector(".playername").value;
    var playerContact = document.querySelector(".playercontact").value;
    var playerAddress = document.querySelector(".playeraddress").value;
    var playerGender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked').value;
    var playerID = document.querySelector(".playerID").value;


    var customerIDProof = document.querySelector(".customeridproof").value;
    var customerIDProofTextBox = document.querySelector(".customeridprooftextbox").value;
    var membershipFor = document.querySelector(".membershipfor").value;
    var membershipType = document.querySelector(".membershiptype").value;
    //console.log(playerBirthday,playerName,playerContact,playerAddress,playerGender,customerIDProof,customerIDProofTextBox,membershipFor,membershipType);


    if (playerID == "") {
        document.querySelector(".playerIDlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank"
        // console.log("ID cannot be blank");
    }
    else if (playerBirthday == "") {
        document.querySelector(".playerbirthdaylabel").innerHTML = "*Select Date"
    }
    else if (playerContact == "") {
        document.querySelector(".playercontactlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (playerName == "") {
        document.querySelector(".playernamelabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
    }
    else if ((!playerGender == "Male") && (!playerGender == "Female")) {
        document.querySelector(".genderlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (playerAddress == "") {
        document.querySelector(".playeraddresslabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (customerIDProof == "---Select---") {
        document.querySelector(".customeridprooflabel").innerHTML = "*Select value";
    }
    else if (customerIDProofTextBox == "") {
        document.querySelector(".customeridprooflabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
    }
    else if (membershipFor == "---Select---") {
        document.querySelector(".membershipforlabel").innerHTML = "*Select value";
    }
    else if (membershipType == "---Select---") {
        document.querySelector(".membershiptypelabel").innerHTML = "*Select value";
    }
    else {
        addPlayerList.push({
            "ID": playerIDvalue,
            "DOB": playerBirthday,
            "Gender": playerGender,
            "Address": playerAddress,
            "IDProof": customerIDProof,
            "IDProofValue": customerIDProofTextBox,
            "membershipFor": membershipFor,
            "membershipType": membershipType,
            "playerContact": playerContact,
            "playerName": playerName
        });
    }




    console.log(addPlayerList);
    return false;
}
```

**managePlayers.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manage Players</title>

    <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="managePlayers">

    <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW PLAYERS, ADD PLAYERS USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showplayers" onclick="showplayers();">Show Players</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addplayers" onclick="addplayers()">Add Players</button>

    <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION FORM OF CUSTOMER -->

    <table class="customerregistration" id="customerregistration">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <Label>ID :</Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="playerID" id="playerID">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playerIDlabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>DOB :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" id="playerbirthday" class="playerbirthday">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playerbirthdaylabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Name :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="playername" id="playername">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playernamelabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Gender :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="playergender" id="femaleplayer"> Female
                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="playergender" id="maleplayer"> Male
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="genderlabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Contact :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="playercontact" id="playercontact">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playercontactlabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Address :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <textarea class="playeraddress" id="playeraddress" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playeraddresslabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>ID Proof :</label>
                <select class="customeridproof" id="customeridproof">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="license">License</option>
                    <option value="aadhaar">Aadhaar</option>
                    <option value="passport">Passport</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="customeridprooftextbox">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="customeridprooflabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Membership For :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="membershipfor" id="membershipfor">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="court">Court</option>
                    <option value="tournament">Tournament</option>
                    <option value="both">Both</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="membershipforlabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Membership Type :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="membershiptype" id="membershiptype">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="halfyearly">Half Yearly</option>
                    <option value="annually">Annually</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="membershiptypelabel"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success saveplayer" onclick="savePlayer()">SAVE</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- ADDING INDEX.JS -->
    <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Screenshots**

[image: managePlayers.html page with two buttons]

[image: Table with input fields gets displayed on Add Player button click]

[image: Checking Validation by not selecting either of the radio button but getting null value error]

**Any solution please  ?**

Comment: give a default selection to one of the option, this will force user to add if it is wrong.

Comment: AlwaysHelping : brother it's somehow not working in my case...i mean when i click save without selecting either of the radio button...then it show me error ie. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: AlwaysHelping : i have used the code provided by you ...but somehow it is showing null value error when i click on save without selecting either of the radio button...

Comment: @MohitKumarSharma All good. I have deleted my working answer since it did not helped as per you. But its working fine in answer. Please check your code you have other issues in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked) property of your input to see which `gender` was `checked` while saving the player and push that `value` to your `array`

The `checked` property will return `true` or `false` for each radio button and will assign a `value` to your var `playerGender` - In the **instance** of that you have **not** selected any radio button the var `playerGender` will be undefined and then we can the error message.

I have added the working code in demo and if you do not select anything in the gender you will see this message `*Cannot be blanked`

**Working Demo**

```js
// --------------TESTING CODE FOR LOGIN PAGE LOGIN BUTTON CLICK----------------

var istableCreated = false;
var email, password, playerIDvalue = 0;
var addPlayerList = [];
var addtournamentsList = [];
var addTrainersList = [];
var addMatchList = [];
var addFeesList = [];


//------------------------------------"MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE"----------------------------------

//--------------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SHOWING PLAYERS OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE--------------------------
function showplayers() {
  document.querySelector("#customerregistration").style.display = "none";

  if (istableCreated == false) {


    istableCreated = true;

    var myTable = document.createElement("table");
    myTable.className = "table-responsive";
    myTable.id = "table-responsive";
    myTable.style.marginLeft = "15%";
    document.body.appendChild(myTable);

    var maintr = document.createElement("tr");
    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr);

    var thID = document.createElement("th");
    thID.innerHTML = "ID";
    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thID);

    var thplayerName = document.createElement("th");
    thplayerName.innerHTML = "Player Name";
    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thplayerName);

    // var thDOB = document.createElement("th");
    // thDOB.innerHTML = "DOB";
    // document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thDOB);

    // var thGender = document.createElement("th");
    // thGender.innerHTML = "Gender";
    // document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thGender);

    var thAddress = document.createElement("th");
    thAddress.innerHTML = "Address";
    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thAddress);

    // var thIDProof = document.createElement("th");
    // thIDProof.innerHTML = "ID Proof";
    // document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thIDProof);

    // var thIDProofValue = document.createElement("th");
    // thIDProofValue.innerHTML = "Value";
    // document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thIDProofValue);

    // var thmembershipFor = document.createElement("th");
    // thmembershipFor.innerHTML = "Membership For";
    // document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thmembershipFor);

    // var thmembershipType = document.createElement("th");
    // thmembershipType.innerHTML = "Membership Type";
    // document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thmembershipType);

    var thcontact = document.createElement("th");
    thcontact.innerHTML = "Contact";
    document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(maintr).appendChild(thcontact);


    //-------------TESTING CODE FOR FETCHING ONLINE DATA FROM API AND CREATING TABLE ROWS--------------


    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // console.log(this.responseText);
        var JSONarr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(JSONarr);

        // ----------SUPER TESTING CODE-----------

        for (var i = 0; i < JSONarr.length; i++) {
          console.log(JSONarr[i].id, JSONarr[i].name, JSONarr[i].address.city, JSONarr[i].address.zipcode);

          var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
          document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr);
          var tdID = document.createElement("td");
          tdID.innerHTML = `${JSONarr[i].id}`;
          document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdID);

          var tdplayerName = document.createElement("td");
          tdplayerName.innerHTML = `${JSONarr[i].name}`;
          document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdplayerName);

          var tdAddress = document.createElement("td");
          tdAddress.innerHTML = `${JSONarr[i].address.city}`;
          document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdAddress);

          var tdContact = document.createElement("td");
          tdContact.innerHTML = `${JSONarr[i].phone}`;
          document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdContact);


        }

      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);
    xhttp.send();






    /*
    for (var i = 0; i < addPlayerList.length; i++) {

        console.log(addPlayerList.length);
        var myTr = document.createElement("tr");
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr);
        var tdID = document.createElement("td");
        tdID.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].ID}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdID);

        var tdplayerName = document.createElement("td");
        tdplayerName.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].playerName}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdplayerName);

        var tdDOB = document.createElement("td");
        tdDOB.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].DOB}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdDOB);

        var tdGender = document.createElement("td");
        tdGender.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].Gender}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdGender);

        var tdAddress = document.createElement("td");
        tdAddress.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].Address}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdAddress);

        var tdIDProof = document.createElement("td");
        tdIDProof.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].IDProof}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdIDProof);

        var tdIDProofValue = document.createElement("td");
        tdIDProofValue.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].IDProofValue}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdIDProofValue);

        var tdmembershipFor = document.createElement("td");
        tdmembershipFor.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].membershipFor}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdmembershipFor);

        var tdmembershipType = document.createElement("td");
        tdmembershipType.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].membershipType}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdmembershipType);

        var tdContact = document.createElement("td");
        tdContact.innerHTML = `${addPlayerList[i].playerContact}`;
        document.body.appendChild(myTable).appendChild(myTr).appendChild(tdContact);
    }
    */
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "block";
  }
}



//---------------------TESTING CODE FOR DISPLAYING TABLE FOR ADDING CUSTOMER INFORMATION--------------- 


function addplayers() {

  // playerIDvalue += 1;
  document.querySelector("#customerregistration").style.display = "block";
  if (istableCreated) {
    document.querySelector("#table-responsive").style.display = "none";
  }
  // document.querySelector(".playerID").value = playerIDvalue;
}



//--------------------------TESTING CODE FOR SAVING CUSTOMER INFORMATION OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE-----------------------------



function savePlayer() {
  console.log("data saved successfully...");
  var playerBirthday = document.querySelector(".playerbirthday").value;
  var playerName = document.querySelector(".playername").value;
  var playerContact = document.querySelector(".playercontact").value;
  var playerAddress = document.querySelector(".playeraddress").value;
  var playerID = document.querySelector(".playerID").value;

  var playerGender
  if (document.getElementById('femaleplayer').checked) {
    playerGender = document.getElementById('femaleplayer').value;
  } else if (document.getElementById('maleplayer').checked) {
    playerGender = document.getElementById('maleplayer').value;
  }

   if (playerGender == undefined) {
document.querySelector(".genderlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";

  }

  var customerIDProof = document.querySelector(".customeridproof").value;
  var customerIDProofTextBox = document.querySelector(".customeridprooftextbox").value;
  var membershipFor = document.querySelector(".membershipfor").value;
  var membershipType = document.querySelector(".membershiptype").value;
  // console.log(playerBirthday,playerName,playerContact,playerAddress,playerGender,customerIDProof,customerIDProofTextBox,membershipFor,membershipType);


  if (playerID == "") {
    document.querySelector(".playerIDlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank"
    // console.log("ID cannot be blank");
  } else if (playerBirthday == "") {
    document.querySelector(".playerbirthdaylabel").innerHTML = "*Select Date"
  } else if (playerContact == "") {
    document.querySelector(".playercontactlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
  } else if (playerName == "") {
    document.querySelector(".playernamelabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
  } else if ((!playerGender == "Male") && (!playerGender == "Female")) {
    document.querySelector(".genderlabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
  } else if (playerAddress == "") {
    document.querySelector(".playeraddresslabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
  } else if (customerIDProof == "---Select---") {
    document.querySelector(".customeridprooflabel").innerHTML = "*Select value";
  } else if (customerIDProofTextBox == "") {
    document.querySelector(".customeridprooflabel").innerHTML = "*Cannot be blank";
  } else if (membershipFor == "---Select---") {
    document.querySelector(".membershipforlabel").innerHTML = "*Select value";
  } else if (membershipType == "---Select---") {
    document.querySelector(".membershiptypelabel").innerHTML = "*Select value";
  } else {
    addPlayerList.push({
      "ID": playerIDvalue,
      "DOB": playerBirthday,
      "Gender": playerGender,
      "Address": playerAddress,
      "IDProof": customerIDProof,
      "IDProofValue": customerIDProofTextBox,
      "membershipFor": membershipFor,
      "membershipType": membershipType,
      "playerContact": playerContact,
      "playerName": playerName
    });
  }

  console.log(addPlayerList);
  return false;
}
```

```css
form {
  margin: auto;
  /* nice thing of auto margin if display:flex; it center both horizontal and vertical :) */
  width: 30%;
}

img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 1.5%;
}

.login {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

label {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.labelemailpassworderror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.labelemailerror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.labelpassworderror {
  color: red;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

h5 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}

.forgotpassword {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  /* margin-left: 25%; */
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

span {
  color: #1a73e8;
}

span:hover {
  color: purple;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF PROFILE PAGE---------------- */

body {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}

.editadminprofile {
  float: right;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE PLAYERS PAGE---------------- */

.showplayers {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addplayers {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.playeraddress {
  resize: none;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE TRAINERS PAGE---------------- */

.showtrainers {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addtrainers {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE TOURNAMENTS PAGE---------------- */

.showtournaments {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addtournaments {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE MATCHES PAGE---------------- */

.showmatches {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addmatches {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE FEES PAGE---------------- */

.showfees {
  margin-right: 30%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}

.addfees {
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  width: 15%;
}


/* ---------------- SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF TABLE OF MANAGE PLAYER PAGE ---------------- */

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table th,
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  width: 5%;
}


/*-------------- SETING CSS PROPERTIES OF CUSTOMER REGISTRATION FORM-------------*/

.customerregistration {
  margin-top: 5%;
  display: none;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 30%;
}

.customeraddress {
  resize: none;
}


/*-------------- SETING CSS PROPERTIES OF TRAINER REGISTRATION FORM-------------*/

.trainerregistration {
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 32%;
  display: none;
}

.traineraddress {
  resize: none;
}


/*-------------- SETING CSS PROPERTIES OF TOURNAMENT REGISTRATION FORM-------------*/

.tournamentregistration {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 32%;
}


/*---------------SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MATCH REGISTRATION-----------------*/

.matchregistration {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 35%;
}


/* -------------SETTING CSS PROPERTIES OF MANAGE FEES---------------------- */

.feesregistration {
  margin-top: 5%;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 35%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Manage Players</title>

  <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

</head>

<body class="managePlayers">

  <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW PLAYERS, ADD PLAYERS USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showplayers" onclick="showplayers();">Show Players</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addplayers" onclick="addplayers()">Add Players</button>

  <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION FORM OF CUSTOMER -->

  <table class="customerregistration" id="customerregistration">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <Label>ID :</Label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="playerID" id="playerID">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="playerIDlabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>DOB :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="date" id="playerbirthday" class="playerbirthday">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="playerbirthdaylabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Name :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="playername" id="playername">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="playernamelabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Gender :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="playergender" id="femaleplayer" required> Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="playergender" id="maleplayer" required> Male
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="genderlabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Contact :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="playercontact" id="playercontact">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="playercontactlabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Address :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea class="playeraddress" id="playeraddress" cols="20" rows="3"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="playeraddresslabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>ID Proof :</label>
        <select class="customeridproof" id="customeridproof">
          <option value="select">---Select---</option>
          <option value="license">License</option>
          <option value="aadhaar">Aadhaar</option>
          <option value="passport">Passport</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="customeridprooftextbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="customeridprooflabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Membership For :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="membershipfor" id="membershipfor">
          <option value="select">---Select---</option>
          <option value="court">Court</option>
          <option value="tournament">Tournament</option>
          <option value="both">Both</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="membershipforlabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Membership Type :</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="membershiptype" id="membershiptype">
          <option value="select">---Select---</option>
          <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
          <option value="halfyearly">Half Yearly</option>
          <option value="annually">Annually</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label class="membershiptypelabel"></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success saveplayer" onclick="savePlayer()">SAVE</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>



  <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
  <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- ADDING INDEX.JS -->
  <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]').checked ;
if(gender == true){
  return true;
 }else {
  return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use script to check whether radio input is selected or not.

```
    //getting value of radio button
    let radioInput = $('input[name=gender]:checked').val();

    //checking for its value, if it is undefined nothing is selected.
    if(radioInput){
       //do something with value.
    }else{
      alert('Nothing selected');
    }
```

Comment: OP is **not** using `jQuery`. Its pure `Javascript!` Just FYI